# wikidata extract

Tags: wikidata, excel

I have a list of wikidata entity IDs (i.e. Tour Eiffel Q243, Big Ben Q41225...), and a list of properties (i.e. coordinates P625, country P18 ...).

Is there any way to gather and extract in Excel (or csv) a table with the information?

What I look for is something like:

[[image: table[1]]

Answer (score 5):

Try [Tabernacle](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/tabernacle.html). Seems to be exactly what you search. The downloaded resultset is in TSV format, and can be imported in Excel.

*You'll need to have a Wikimedia account to work with Tabernacle and some other WMF wikis related tools.*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) for that. It can import roughly any tabular dataset and the latest version allows you to extend you data with Wikidata easily.

[image: screencast of the feature in OpenRefine]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Wikidata SPARQL endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/) web UI.

Paste the query below in the query form, press "Run", then press "Download".

```
SELECT
?placeLabel
?coordinate
?countryLabel
?cityLabel
WHERE
{
  VALUES (?place)
  {
    (wd:Q243)
    (wd:Q41225)
    # ...
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P625 ?coordinate }
  OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P17 ?country }
  OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P131 ?city }
  # ...
  SERVICE wikibase:label
    { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

Some issues are possible, please write a comment if you experience any problem with your query.

P.S. `wikibase:label` is a [magic](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service) Wikidata service.